# SharePoint 2010: formula that counts number of months till end of year

Tags: date, sharepoint-2010, formula

I am looking for a formula, that will count number of remaining months from a specific date (date field chosen by user) till end of 2012 year.

Platform is SharePoint Server 2010

Example:

- User will choose date 14.4.2012
- Another field will return number 9 in calculated formula

Answer (score 0):

```
=12-(MONTH([datecolumn])+1)
```

Should do the trick.